# Calculate profit of successive years by adding profit of previous year

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Sample data and expected result is provided in the image:

[image: sample data]

We need to add the profit of previous year with the successive year and display the data in the format given in he image (sample data is also provided in the image).

Please help me with the SQL query to solve this problem.

Comment: Please include all relevant details of your question (such as the SQL code and data) directly in the question.  Do not paste external links.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write this using the window function.

```
SELECT
    Year,
    SUM(Profit) OVER(ORDER BY Year) AS Total_Profit
FROM your_table
ORDER BY Year
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the world's simplest recursive CTE which you could have googled.
But here it is:

```
declare @years table(y int, p int)
insert @years values (2015,1000),(2016,2000),(2017,500),(2018,1000)
; with cumulative as
(
    select top 1 * from @years order by y
    union all
    select y.y, y.p+c.p
    from @years y
    join cumulative c on y.y=c.y+1
)
select * from cumulative
```

Result:

```
y       p
2015    1000
2016    3000
2017    3500
2018    4500
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum over partition :

```
WITH V1 AS (
    SELECT 2015 AS YEAR, 1000 AS PROFIT FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 2016 AS YEAR, 2000 AS PROFIT FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 2017 AS YEAR, 500 AS PROFIT FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 2018 AS YEAR, 1000 AS PROFIT FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
    V1.YEAR
    , PROFIT --- You can comment it if not needed
    , SUM(PROFIT) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY YEAR RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS PROFIT_CUM
FROM V1;
```